Где и как написать виджет для faceit.com для обс
Не понимаю как написать виджет для faceit.com, для вывода статистики после каждого сыгранного матча автоматически в реальном времени на этой платформе в моем обс студио путем выбора источника.
Сайты для сбора статистики, которые я смог найти и с помощью которых, имеются виджеты приватно для определенного круга лиц.

developers

stats

faceit

faceit

faceit - Это как пример того, чего я хочу добиться:

clip



Не разобрался как сделать? Тоже бы хотела себе на стрим запилить. Нашла вот такую тему на гитхабе-https://github.com/mtricolici98/faceit_csgo_stats_for_obs правда не понятно то ли это + не могу разобраться как API KEY для фасика сделать, точнее я сделала, но походу чет не так XD
